# Word - Change styles without changing formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I've been given a document where the majority of the text is styled as `Heading 1` for some reason. I want to change it to `Normal` without changing the formatting - is this possible?

[image]

I want the font, font size and which text is bolded or italicised to remain the same, but the paragraph settings and syntactic meaning to be set to normal (In the navigation pane each paragraph irritatingly comes as a heading, for example)

Comment: Unclear what are you asking,  that is a kind of format, it likes now your asking "how to change the format without changing the format?" Confusing…

Comment: I could've been clearer; I want the font, font size and which text is bolded or italicised to remain the same, but the paragraph settings and syntactic meaning to be set to normal (In the navigation pane each paragraph irritatingly comes as a heading, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I've found one way to sort of do it - use a macro (this is the first time I've tried using them). Highlight the required text and click on `View > Macros > Record macro`. Then change the style to `Normal` and change the font back. When finished click `View > Macros > Stop recording`. You can then run the macro every time you highlight the offending paragraphs.

Unfortunately this doesn't preserve bold/italicised, but it is the only method I can think of.